# The current identity has not been registered:

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have successfully issued, imported and pinged a card on Hyperledger composer 0.16.0. However, when I try to execute transactions with the created identity, I get the following errors

> "Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity has not been registered: roger)\n"

I am not sure whether I should now 'bind' the identity to a participant as demonstrated [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/identity-bind.html). I did try this but there is a required certificate file `--certificateFile` which I am not sure where to find. Preliminary checks on .composer folder in my home directory indicate that I have a xxxx-pub and xxxx-priv file on the card details in client-data subdirectory. Would this xxxx-pub act as the required certificate?

Anyway, that was just my attempt at finding the solution but I would really appreciate if anyone could help me resolve the **The current identity has not been registered: roger** error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I tried with the xxxx-pub file and it worked. So use -e /path/to/file/xxxx-pub in the `composer identity bind` command.